# error: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "" while inserting data into the table

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express

I am inserting a response from express api into a postgres table. I have created a table already with a column 'createdon' with type timestamp. In response, I am getting a timestamp which I want to insert in that field.
This is the script I wrote:

```
client.query(`INSERT INTO table (col1, col2,createdon, col3) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING *`, [val1, val2, val3, val4])
```

This is working fine until I get a timestamp in createdon field. If I get empty response for createdon field, it's throwing this error.

How can I bypass this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert a blank timestamp use `null` instead. With `nullif` you can test if the value is empty and replace it with null:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2,createdon, col3) 
VALUES ($1, $2, NULLIF($3,'')::timestamp, $4) 
RETURNING *
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/b3DuU7oz)

Comment: Thanks, assigning timestamp to nullif worked. :).  ```NULLIF($3,'')::timestamp```